# Incorrect Myanmar font itext7

Tags: fonts, itext

I am having trouble in showing the correct Myanmar font.

The desired font:
 [image]

Whereas the font produced by code: [image]

We tried all fonts like mm3, Myanmar3, NotoSansMyanmar but it is not giving the desired result. It seems issue with font only and not java code. Please let me know the font which we can try to ensure its working fine.

In texts:
Desired font - ၀န်ထမ်းလစာပေးချေလွှာ

I am not able to paste the code font, as the chrome is changing it to the above font. You can see highlighted letter in image needs to be interchanged.

Comment: is it possible that you place the actual text here, instead of the screenshot? just for ease of reproducibility.

Comment: @AndréLemos -  Please refer edited question.

Comment: Are you using the itext caligraph extension?

Comment: @PauloSoares - No we are not using itext caligraph